# SQL - How to create a column with data from another line

Tags: sql, date, row

I need to have another column with date from next row.

I have:

```
job   sdate     status
1     1/1/13      A 
1     5/1/13      B
1     20/1/13     C
2     1/1/13      A 
2     7/1/13      B
3     2/1/13      A
```

i need:

```
job   sdate     status   edate
1     1/1/13      A      5/1/13  
1     5/1/13      B      20/1/13
1     20/1/13     C      (null)
2     1/1/13      A      7/1/13
2     7/1/13      B      (null)
3     2/1/13      A      (null)
```

Comment: *Next row* requires something to order your data by - what do you want your rows to be ordered by to define *next row* and *previous row* ?

Comment: i need this but i just want next row if it's the same job..

Comment: job and sdate... now i have
`select job, sdate,status,
       (select min(sdate)
        from t t2
        where t2.job = t.Projeto and t2.sdate > t.sdate
       ) as edate
from t`
the quert tooks more then 30minuts :\ and the t tooks 1second...

Comment: What **database** is this for? (SQL is just the query language - not a database) And what kind of indexes do you have on your tables shown?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using the `lead()` function:

```
select job, sdate, status,
       lead(sdate) over (partition by job order by sdate) as edate
from t;
```

Many databases support lead, such as Oracle, Postgres, and SQL Server 2012.  Some do not, such as Access, MySQL, and SQL Server prior to 2012.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68b32/190) is the SQL Fiddle that demonstrates that the first version works.

An alternative formulation that will work in any database is to use a subquery:

```
select job, sdate, status,
       (select min(sdate)
        from t t2
        where t2.job = t.job and t2.sdate > t.sdate
       ) as edate
from t;
```

Comment: like that i think that i will get for example for job 1 the edate as 20/1/13 but i want as the example...

Comment: @RuiSantos . . . The first version works (and worked).  I fixed the second version.

Comment: the problem this solution is that the lead doesn't work on my sql server.
and the second one took so many time..
what i have is a view as t so do you know a way more fast to do it?

Comment: @RuiSantos . . . The performance on the second one will be much, much improved if you create the index `t(job, sdate)`.

Comment: can you explain how to do it?
i have now
`select job, sdate,status,
       (select min(sdate)
        from t t2
        where t2.job = t.Projeto and t2.sdate > t.sdate
       ) as edate
from t`
the query tooks more then 30minuts :\ and the t tooks 1 second...

Comment: @RuiSantos . . . `create index t_job_sdate on t(job, sdate)`.  I do note that your join condition is different from the one in my answer.  It has `t2.job = t.Projeto`.  The two fields should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Clarify your question in more detail.

If you need to add column and you want to use that column while adding new record then you can do it easily.